# Writelines writes lines without newline, Just fills the file

Tags: python

I have a program that writes a list to a file. 
The list is a list of pipe delimited lines and the lines should be written to the file like this:

```
123|GSV|Weather_Mean|hello|joe|43.45
122|GEV|temp_Mean|hello|joe|23.45
124|GSI|Weather_Mean|hello|Mike|47.45
```

BUT it wrote them line this ahhhh:

```
123|GSV|Weather_Mean|hello|joe|43.45122|GEV|temp_Mean|hello|joe|23.45124|GSI|Weather_Mean|hello|Mike|47.45
```

This program wrote all the lines into like one line without any line breaks.. This hurts me a lot and I gotta figure-out how to reverse this but anyway, where is my program wrong here? I thought write lines should write lines down the file rather than just write everything to one line..

```
fr = open(sys.argv[1], 'r') # source file
fw = open(sys.argv[2]+"/masked_"+sys.argv[1], 'w') # Target Directory Location

for line in fr:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "":
        continue
    columns = line.strip().split('|')
    if columns[0].find("@") > 1:
        looking_for = columns[0] # this is what we need to search
    else:
        looking_for = "Dummy@dummy.com"
    if looking_for in d:
        # by default, iterating over a dictionary will return keys
            new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
            line_list.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_idx = str(len(d)+1)
        d[looking_for] = new_idx
        kv = open(sys.argv[3], 'a')
        kv.write(looking_for+" "+new_idx+'\n')
        kv.close()
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)
fw.writelines(line_list)
```

Comment: It seems like you are not appending `"\n"` anywhere in your `line_list`.

Comment: You could take a look at [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Where do I add the "\n"? Do I add it to the list object??

Comment: I just wanna say it's really cool coming back to Python in 2022 and finding that a question from 9 years ago about a function called "writelines" that DOESN'T WRITE LINES is still relevant. What was I thinking, trying to write lines to a file with a method called writelines? Silly me. I'm going to upload a module to PyPi and all it's going to do is change the method name to writeline.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is actually a pretty common problem for newcomers to Python—especially since, across the standard library and popular third-party libraries, some reading functions strip out newlines, but almost no writing functions (except the `log`-related stuff) add them.

So, there's a lot of Python code out there that does things like:

```
fw.write('\n'.join(line_list) + '\n')
```

(writing a single string) or

```
fw.writelines(line + '\n' for line in line_list)
```

Either one is correct, and of course you could even write your own writelinesWithNewlines function that wraps it up…

But you should only do this if you can't avoid it.

It's better if you can create/keep the newlines in the first place—as in Greg Hewgill's suggestions:

```
line_list.append(new_line + "\n")
```

And it's even better if you can work at a higher level than raw lines of text, e.g., by using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module in the standard library, as esuaro suggests.

For example, right after defining `fw`, you might do this:

```
cw = csv.writer(fw, delimiter='|')
```

Then, instead of this:

```
new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
line_list.append(new_line)
```

You do this:

```
row_list.append(d[looking_for] + columns[1:])
```

And at the end, instead of this:

```
fw.writelines(line_list)
```

You do this:

```
cw.writerows(row_list)
```

Finally, your design is "open a file, then build up a list of lines to add to the file, then write them all at once". If you're going to open the file up top, why not just write the lines one by one? Whether you're using simple writes or a `csv.writer`, it'll make your life simpler, and your code easier to read. (Sometimes there can be simplicity, efficiency, or correctness reasons to write a file all at once—but once you've moved the `open` all the way to the opposite end of the program from the `write`, you've pretty much lost any benefits of all-at-once.)

Comment: all of this because python does not do the obvious with `writelines`

Comment: Wow. This is ridiculous behaviour on Python's part: readlines() *should strip* newlines, but doesn't, and writelines() *should add* newlines, but doesn't. The whole point of having readlines and writelines is so that you can easily read and write lists. Mildly infuriating!

Comment: Does it worth a PEP like f.writelines(lines, end='\n') ?

Comment: Yeah, gotta say, this is a helpful answer, but writelines not...you know, writing separate lines...is a real headscratcher.

Comment: In case line_list is recently prepared it is  legit to use fw.writelines([f"{line}\n" for line in line_list])

Answer (score 63):

The [documentation for `writelines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) states:

> `writelines()` does not add line separators

So you'll need to add them yourself. For example:

```
    line_list.append(new_line + "\n")
```

whenever you append a new item to `line_list`.

Comment: +1. This is the simplest solution, and almost certainly the most appropriate if the OP doesn't want to switch to something higher-level like `csv`.

Comment: What an awful name for the function just for the sake of "matching" readlines.

Comment: worse than awful name: awful *functionality*

Comment: Doc for Python 3 - https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines

Answer (score 51):

As others have noted, `writelines` is a misnomer (it ridiculously does not add newlines to the end of each line).

To do that, explicitly add it to each line:

```
with open(dst_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(s + '\n' for s in lines)
```

Answer (score 12):

`writelines()` does not add line separators. You can alter the list of strings by using `map()` to add a new `\n` (line break) at the end of each string.

```
items = ['abc', '123', '!@#']
items = map(lambda x: x + '\n', items)
w.writelines(items)
```

Comment: This here is byfar the best optimised approach. as the writelines will run the map iterator.

Answer (score 11):

Credits to `Brent Faust`.

---

Python >= 3.6 with format string:

```
with open(dst_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(f'{s}\n' for s in lines)
```

`lines` can be a `set`.

If you are oldschool (like me) you may add `f.write('\n')` below the second line.

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned, and counter to what the method name would imply, `writelines` does not add line separators. This is a textbook case for a generator. Here is a contrived example:

```
def item_generator(things):
    for item in things:
        yield item
        yield '\n'

def write_things_to_file(things):
    with open('path_to_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.writelines(item_generator(things))
```

Benefits: adds newlines explicitly without modifying the input or output values or doing any messy string concatenation. And, critically, does not create any new data structures in memory. IO (writing to a file) is when that kind of thing tends to actually matter. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Definitely the simplest way to add a newline char to every string...

Answer (score 2):

As we have well established here, `writelines` does not append the newlines for you.  But, what everyone seems to be missing, is that it doesn't have to when used as a direct "counterpart" for `readlines()` and the initial read persevered the newlines!

When you open a file for reading in **binary mode** (via `'rb'`), then use `readlines()` to fetch the file contents into memory, split by line, the newlines remain attached to the end of your lines!  So, if you then subsequently write them back, you don't likely want `writelines` to append anything!

So if, you do something like:

```
with open('test.txt','rb') as f: lines=f.readlines()
with open('test.txt','wb') as f: f.writelines(lines)
```

You should end up with the same file content you started with.

Comment: And when exactly do you want to read a file just to write it back?

Comment: You are taking the code example far too literally.  I didn't include a faux context and extraneous example code for when you would read a file and write it back.  There would be something in between normally where you would modify the content.  Or, you might be "copying" / tweaking a source file into a destination file.  The point is the readlines/writelines counterparts handle this issue implicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to insist on the issue. It's just that most of the time when I read a file and write back to it or to another file, one of the methods I call is `.strip` or '.rstrip()` so in my workflow this would just never occur.

Comment: Np. I have often done the same, but if you landed on this page, you might want to change that practice in some use cases, where you want to preserve the line endings, you can avoid having to explicitly append them by keeping this post in mind.

Answer (score 2):

As we want to only separate lines, and the `writelines` function in python does not support adding separator between lines, I have written the simple code below which best suits this problem:

```
sep = "\n" # defining the separator
new_lines = sep.join(lines) # lines as an iterator containing line strings
```

and finally:

```
with open("file_name", 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(new_lines)
```

and you are done.

Comment: Since you are posting an answer to an older question, it would be most helpful that you support your purported answer with some code and  the output that results from using your code.

Comment: There is no point in calling writelines if you joined the lines to single string beforehand.