# Write each prime number in different line (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, random, io

I would like to write random prime numbers in new lines to a text file, but when I run my script it writes all numbers in one line. It's very likely that I don't understand something correctly.

This is my original code:

```
import random
file = open("prime.txt", "w")
i = 0
while( i<=100 ):
    temp=str(random.randint(1, 500) )
    file.writelines(temp)
    i += 1
file.close()
```

According to the answers, I just have to use the `write()` method with newline character (`\n`) instead of the `writelines()` method.

Comment: Since you're only writing one string at atime, I think you just want `file.write(temp + "\n")`

Comment: the answer that CollinD gave should work for you, for more info you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730107/writelines-writes-lines-without-newline-just-fills-the-file) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a newline when writing each number to the file. Also use `file.write()` instead of `file.writelines()`. Just use this as your code:

```
import random
file = open("primes.txt", "w")
i=0
while(i<=100):
    temp=str(random.randint(1,500))
    file.write(temp  + "\n")  #add a newline after each number
    i+=1
file.close()
```

Comment: In your example, you want to use simply `file.write()`

writelines() is for a sequence of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not sure about using write() and writelines().

Answer (score 3):

[`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) doesn't add line separators (which seems weird considering `readlines` removes them).  You'll have to add them manually.

```
lines = ['{0}\n'.format(random.randint(1,500)) for i in range(100)]
file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: A little pedantic, but it's expecting any sequence of strings, not just a list. =)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a sequence to writelines, you can use a generator expression and also use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open your files replacing your while loop with a [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
import random
with  open("prime.txt", "w") as f:
   f.writelines(str(random.randint(1,500))+"\n" for _ in range(100))
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems really useful.