# Manipulating and replace 1st string and maintain 2nd string line using python

Tags: python, string, text

I have a file (sysid.txt) that consist of multiple line of data (systemid and hostname) as follow

```
0192.4500.0000 uue01.re1                              
0192.4500.0010 ccu01.re1                              
0192.4500.0110 uue02.re1                               
0192.4500.0001 core1.re2
```

Based from info and help here, the 1st string(numbers) successfully replace as require but the 2nd string(hostname) missing and the output presented in single line when I run the code below.

```
file1 = open('sysid.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('sysip.txt', 'w')
file1_cont = file1.readlines()
for line in file1_cont:
    line = line.replace('.', '')
    f = itemgetter(slice(0,3), slice(3,6), slice(6,9), slice(9,12))
    line = '.'.join(f(line.replace('.','')))
    line = '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(*map(int, f(line.replace('.', ''))))
    file2.write(line)
    print(line)
```

the output of sysip.txt

```
10.89.0.010.89.0.110.89.0.3210.89.0.3310.89.0.3410.89.0.3510.89.0.64
```

Read each line, I would like to replace 1st string(numbers) and maintain 2nd string (hostname) as below

```
192.45.0.0 uue01.re1                              
192.45.0.10 ccu01.re1                              
192.45.0.110 uue02.re1                               
192.45.0.1 core1.re2
```

How can i manipulate 1st string/numbers and save the output line (file2.write(line)) in new line and at the same time remain the 2nd string as above.

Thank you for your support and guidance.

#

updated list.txt...

```
System ID      Hostname                                        
0192.4500.0000 uue01.re1                              
0192.4500.0010 ccu01.re1                              
0192.4500.0110 uue02.re1                               
0192.4500.0001 core1.re2 

{master}
```

Comment: see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list.txt:

```
0192.4500.0000 uue01.re1                              
0192.4500.0010 ccu01.re1                              
0192.4500.0110 uue02.re1                               
0192.4500.0001 core1.re2
```

**Hence**:

```
def removeZeros(ip):
    # splits the ip by "."
    # converts the words to integeres to remove leading removeZeros
    # convert back the integer to string and join them back to a string
    new_ip = ".".join([str(int(i)) for i in ip.split(".")])
    return new_ip

logFile = "list.txt"
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

for line in content:
    line = line[1:].split(" ")[0]
    line =  removeZeros(line).replace(removeZeros(line).split(".", 2)[1],removeZeros(line).split(".", 2)[1][:-2] + ".0")
    print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
192.45.0.0
192.45.0.10 
192.45.0.110 
192.45.0.1
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to overwrite the new ip `list` to the same file, you can create two separate lists to store the `ips` and the `text`:

```
logFile = "list.txt"
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
ipList = []
stList = []
for line in content:
    stList.append(line[1:].split(" ")[1])
    line = line[1:].split(" ")[0]
    line =  removeZeros(line).replace(removeZeros(line).split(".", 2)[1],removeZeros(line).split(".", 2)[1][:-2] + ".0")
    ipList.append(line)
    # print(line)

with open(logFile, "w") as f:
    for index in range(len(ipList)):
        f.write(str(ipList[index]) + " " + str(stList[index]) + "\n")
```

**OUTPUT (from the file)**:

```
192.45.0.0 uue01.re1
192.45.0.10 ccu01.re1
192.45.0.110 uue02.re1
192.45.0.1 core1.re2
```

**EDIT 3**:

In order to remove the first and last line, use slicing:

Replace this line:

```
for line in content:
```

with this:

```
for line in content[1:-1]:  # after the first and before the last line
```

Comment: Hi...I'm getting error below --> stList.append(line[1:].split(" ")[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @chenoi The above code is tested. Do you have the same data like I do in the above `list.txt`?

Comment: Hi sir, the list got header and string at the end of the file... when i manually delete the header and last string...and just the data....run code ok...i have updated the list.txt... how can i remove the header and the last line?

Comment: @chenoi using slicing, check the Edit 3.

Comment: U r the man sir!...i tried using [1:-1] before... but...i add wrongly.... thank goodness u point me to the right point...thank you sir.

Comment: @chenoi no worries, you may accept the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> How can i manipulate 1st string/numbers [...] and at the same time remain the 2nd string as above.

It seems you can split the string on the space character before you replace the points, to only modify the part where you need to.

Example:

```
s = "0192.4500.0010 ccu01.re1                              "
numbers, host = s.split()
numbers = numbers.replace(".", "")
# TODO: fill in appropriate conversions with `numbers` here
print(numbers, host)
```

The output is:

```
019245000010 ccu01.re1
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

---

> How can i [...] save the output line (file2.write(line)) in new line

When writing the output to the file, newline characters are not added automatically. You need to add them to the string yourself.

Example:

```
numbers = "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(*numbers)
line = "{} {}\n".format(numbers, host)
outf.write(line)
```

Also, it is a good habit to use the `with` statement to open and eventually close the files.

For reference:

- [Writelines writes lines without newline, Just fills the file..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13730107/1025391)
- [How to open a file using the open with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282967/1025391)

Comment: Not an output OP wanted.

Comment: @DirtyBit Copying the missing parts from the OP is left as an excercise to the reader.

Comment: ip, hostname = line.split()
    print(ip, hostname)          ....Im getting error below-->      ip, hostname = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @chenoi You have a line not adhering to the format, e.g., an empty line or one containing more or less than two words. You might want to add [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and [skip such lines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue), for example.